# Get name/version number WMI/Powershell query (eventually for all machines on domain)

Tags: powershell, wmi

I'm completely new at Powershell and trying to ultimately run a query for all systems on my domain to get name, version info, and key of all installed Microsoft/Symantec software.

Before I mess around on the domain (although if anyone can complete the query I'd be grateful), I'm trying to do it on my own machine.

So far using

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name, Version, IdentifyingNumber
```

seems to work, but it gives me all software on the system. I'm trying to add a | Where-Object {-like 'Microsoft Corporation') but I'm unaware of the correct syntax to use.

Also could anyone direct me to a good resource on how to get this to run on all machines on the domain?

Comment: I think the win32_OperatingSystem class might work better for you.

Comment: When I run use that class it just returns the actual OS. Am I missing something? I need more than just that information.

Comment: Well I got it to work using

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name, Version, IdentifyingNumber, Version | Where-Object {$.Vendor -like "*Microsoft*"}

BUT, if I try to add the OR oprerator to add "*Symantec*" it stops working, where do I place that?

Comment: Powershell only shows certain properties of common WMI classes. To see all the properties: Get-WMIObject win32_OperatingSystem | Format-List *

Comment: Where-Object {($.Vendor -like "Microsoft") -OR ($_.Vendor -like 'Symantec')}

Comment: I'd prefer `Where-Object { 'Microsoft','Symantec' -contains $_.Vendor }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the examples for [Where-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849715.aspx).  They show how to filter properly.

Also, [Get-WmiObject](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849824.aspx) can be *painfully* slow.  Better to add the filter using its `Query` or `Filter` parameters.  Again, [read the help topic](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849824.aspx) for some examples.

Comment: If this is running across the whole domain, using `gwmi`'s built-in filter/query is the only way to go, from an efficiency perspective.